# Find shortest path from A to B through C

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am working on design a algorithm for indoor route planing. I hope brilliant people here could give some advices.

I have a source points A and Destnation point B. To go to B from A, I need to go through a staircase c. There are many staircases c1 c2 c3... in the building.

My current algorithm is to use the staircass with the smellest geometrical distance to the source point. However, this is not always optimal since the nearest staircase may be in the opposite direction of the destination point.

Another approach I tried is to compare the real cost for each staircase(using Dijkstra's algorithm), and choose the the staircase with the minimum cost. This way is granteed to be optimal, but it's too costly. It takes too long for calculation.

I am wondering if there is a way to compromise between them..

Comment: Is there only one staircase in between points A and B? How many potential staircases are there?

Comment: Djikstra's algorithm should be an efficient way to solve this question. If your performance is poor, it's possible you implemented it incorrectly. Show us your source code.

Comment: I abstracted the problem. We have a database to store all pathways. The database have more than 10,0000 rows. A Djikstra's query to find shortest points from A to B takes half second. Our building have 5-6 staircases, do a Djikstra's query for every staircase takes more than 4 seconds. @NShumway

Comment: We have 5-6 staircases. @Hirsh

Comment: It would be helpful if you state the problem in its entirety rather than trying to abstract it. What is contained in the 100,000 rows and when does the calculation need to be performed?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm, including the tradeoffs involved in Bounded Relaxation. I note that the article says this was invented for a prototype indoor robot.

Comment: So you have graph that have just the start and goal, A and B, and a number of intermediate nodes, staircases C1 ... Cn, with known distances between A and Ci and Ci and B? Or are there more nodes? Why can't you just do A* from A to B, that will necessarily pass through any one Ci, instead of testing all the combinations individually? And are you sure that the bottle neck is actually the path finding and not e.g. the DB lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you run a Djikstra from each of your 5 staircases and save the results in a database (according to your numbers, this takes only a few seconds and is a one-off cost).

Then for each route you wish to plan, you can test going via each of the 5 staircases.  The cost from A->c->B is given by two lookups: one for c->A and one for c->B.

Therefore you can find the optimal route in a total of 10 lookups (2 for each staircase) no matter how many edges are in the database.